# How to Avoid Data Display in Browser Debug Console - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, browser, console

Please let me know how i can avoid data being displayed on Browser debug console in Firefox, Chrome, IE & other's.

I have attached image of the same.

[image: How to Avoid Data being displayed in Browser Console]

Comment: Remove console.log from your code

Comment: I have removed console.log. Still it is showing me. I am new to Angularjs and started learning Angularjs by the Youtube Video provided by fine mentor's like you.

Comment: As shown in his image, he's referring to the POST Headers and JSON responses (usually avaiable in network tabs). Unless you can encrypt your responses, there's nothing you can do by this way.

Comment: Try removing browser cache. `Ctrl+Shift+R`

Comment: Can you provide me with example or Link for encrypting responses in angularjs.

Comment: I have resolved my query.